# Play! framework form redirect not working

Tags: java, playframework, routes

I´m having a problem redirecting from a play! form. I think the problem lies in how I´m handling the routes. The idea is that a user should be able to go to dashboard.html either by going first through index.hmtl using login from with a secruity key, or by typing directly in a valid path containing an access_token (using a qr-code redirection)

What I´m trying to do is as follows:

## 1) login using a form on index.html (route: Application.index)

Here is my form (located in index.html):

```
<form action="@{Dashboard.authenticate()}" method="POST" name="login">
    <input name="key" type="password" maxlength="128" value="${flash.key}">
    <input class="button" id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

## 2) authenticate and redirect to dashboard.html (route: Dashboard.dashboard)

```
public static void dashboard(String access_token) {
   /*
      ...some code
   */

    render(username);
}


public static void authenticate(String key) {
   /*
      ...some code
   */
     dashboard(access_token);
}
```

Here is my route file:

```
# Home page 
GET     /                   Application.index
POST    /dashboard      Dashboard.authenticate
GET     /dashboard      Dashboard.dashboard
```

The dashboard route works fine if I call directly upon dashboard(String access_token) through an URL like: http://localhost:9000/dashboard?access_token=0000
But if i try to login using the login form that calls upon authenticate(String key) I get this URL http://localhost:9000/dashboard?access_token&key=1234 where key is the var being sent to the auth()function. Clearly my fault lies with the routes, but I have tried and tested the logic and I am 100% certain it is sound.
I´m using Play 1.2.4
I have spent two days on this problem and would be most grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

What I forgot to mention...oops was that I am also using jQuery Mobile and the problem had to do with Play! routing being overriden my jQuery Mobile page routing.

I disabled the routing by adding the following script:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;

})
```

Using instructions on the jQuery website: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html I implemented the above but the script needs to referenced in the .hmtml header in the following order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Pere and Wes:) Before coming up with the above solution I tried out your suggestions without results. Turns out by omitting to include the crucial information that I was using jQuery Mobile you did not have the whole picture but the fault lies with me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That actually seems like a bug. Maybe try

```
redirect("/dashboard?access_token="+access_token);
```

instead of

```
dashboard(access_token);
```

Comment: I think you´re right, this is probably a Play! bug.
I tried your suggestion but it doesn´t work since it too returns the uri: http://localhost:9000/dashboard?access_token&key=1234 instead of http://localhost:9000/dashboard?access_token=0000 but access_token and key are separate things. 
However I solved this by using javascript for from authentication and after authentication I call on dashboard?access_token= through changepage in javascript.  This is not my preferred way but it solves the issue for now.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe try printing out access_token to make sure it's actually what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

The Java code seems fine. Just in case, have you tried to change the routes file to:

```
# Home page 
GET     /                   Application.index
GET     /dashboard      Dashboard.dashboard
POST    /dashboard      Dashboard.authenticate
```

moving the GET before the POST (order matters, this should fix it if there is a Play bug on that section).

Another option is to simply rename the POST route, to fix the issue if it's caused by both routes having the same 'path'.

```
# Home page 
GET     /                    Application.index
GET     /dashboard           Dashboard.dashboard
POST    /dashboard/auth      Dashboard.authenticate
```